# Setting isolation.level for kafka with spring cloud stream

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

On a project I'm consuming messages of on partner from a kafka server, the producer is using transactions and it seems that the default configuration of a kafka consumer for isolation.level is read_uncommited by default and they suggest to set the configuration

I have some questions:
Is the default value always isolation.level=read_uncommited or changed over versions?
If I set default isolation.level=read_commited by defaul for kafka binder is there any cost for consumers reading from non transactional producer.

```
      kafka:
        default:
          consumer:
            configuration:
              isolation.level: read_committed
```

What is the best practices setting this value if we have multiple partners/binders and we don't really know if they are using transactions or no.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolation level has always "**read_uncommited**" as default value as I know, but not the case of **enable.idempotence**.
So What you did is a good practice, to be sure that you'll not loose your config if the default value will change.

For the second question :

- If you are using **read_commited** level on a fully non transactional topic, there are no pb
- If your topic is mixed or full transactional you'll be restricted by the broker to read only messages until **LSO** (last stable offset) that's not always equal to the High Watermark 
  => the **LSO** is depending of the state of the ***last transactional message***, so if there is a ***pending*** transaction on a message in the partition **P1** at offset **X** and you received in the meantime other messages in **P1** (**X+1,..., X+n**), those messages will not be part of **LSO** until the last transaction at the offset **X** is committed or aborted => that's the only thing to be aware of when using **read_committed** level.
  Don't hesitate if it's not totally clear.